# For Loop is not working as expected when checking array content in last column

Tags: arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I saved the information of this table in an 2D array using Google Apps Script. The whole array building process worked as aspected.

|  | Area | X | Y | Major | Minor | Angle | SensorNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25049 | 380.500 | 246.500 | 190.953 | 167.023 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 24248 | 393.500 | 247.000 | 192.976 | 159.986 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 18250 | 382.500 | 247.000 | 159.023 | 146.121 | 0 | 3 |

However, as I tried to build a for loop (as seen in the following code) that goes through every column of the first row of the array I did not get the expected output. I tried to tell the loop that when the array content equals "SensorNo" to save the respective n as a new variable and then break the loop. But whenever the array content I'm looking for is in the last column the variable remains undefined...

```
for(n=0;n<fileContentArray[0].length;n++){
  if(fileContentArray[0][n]=="SensorNo"){
    var sensorNoCol=n;
    break;
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.
*Best, Max*

Answer (score 1):

```
function getHeaderColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  const hRow = 1;
  const hA = sh.getRange(hRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let col = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h] = i + 1 });
  return col['SensorNo'];
}
```